# Append text to all members of a class jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a number of input boxes of class "inputbox".  I'd like to append ".00" to the end of each of them.  I tried this:

```
    $('.inputbox').val($(this).val()+".00");
```

But the $(this) doesn't return any value, so I just get ".00" in all the boxes.  Any help on how to get the value from each of those input boxes so I can add to it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`val()` has a callback, you can use it for exactly things like this, where you need to concantenate to the values of many elements in a collection.

```
$('.inputbox').val(function(_, val) { return val + ".00" });
```

Comment: Would you explain what is happening?  I'm still pretty new to jQuery/Javascript, and I don't exactly understand how this works.

Comment: @user3413723 - `val()` can get and set the value, and it also accepts an optional callback function, which is what I'm using here, and inside that callback the second argument is the current value, in this case val, and the you can add something to that and return it, and it's set as the new value. It's pretty nifty and it's explained in the [**documentation for val()**](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2) as well.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery selectors return arrays. But `val()` function can not be used for arrays, it can be used for a single element. So you can use [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) of jQuery:

```
$('.inputbox').each(function(){
   $(this).val($(this).val()+".00");
});
```

Comment: This way works great too; I wish I could check them both!  I checked the other because it's more specific to the val() function.  This one will be helpful in many other cases as well though, I think.